# Access List inside model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following models:

```
public class Furniture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Decimal Retail { get; set; }
    public String Picture { get; set; }
}
public class Quotation
{
    public String zipCode { get; set; }
    public List<Furniture> furnitures { get; set; }
}
```

How can I access the list of furniture in the View with Razor ?
Can we transfer a complex structure (with several levels of substructures) to the MVC view or is MVC view limited to one level structure and IEnumerable ?

Comment: yes we can - if set `Quotation` as model for your view you can access to `furnitures` like this `@Model.furnitures`

Comment: _"Or is MVC view limited to one level structure and IEnumerable?"_ - why would it be? What did you try, do you get an actual error, or is this a hypothetical question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach (var furniture in Model.furnitures)
{
    <p>@furniture.Description</p>
    <p>Retail: @furniture.Retail</p>
    <img src="@furniture.Picture" />
}
```

Something like this. If I understand your wishes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass a complex object to the View in MVC and access its members. You do this by applying the MVVM where you create a ViewModel to pass to the View. This model holds all data to be shown in the View and is created by the Controller.

- More reading: [**How to Use ViewModel with ASP.NET MVC?**](http://sampathloku.blogspot.be/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html)
- Different ViewModel Patterns: [**ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns**](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that is Model.Property is null ?
2. Use foreach loop to access each object in list.
3. Now you can access values of each object.

   ```
   @if (Model.furnitures != null)  
   { 
           foreach (var furniture in Model.furnitures )  
           { 
              <p>Description : @furniture.Description</p>
              <p>Retail : @furniture.Retail </p> 
              <img src="@furniture.Picture" />  
           } 
   }
   ```